# textcat missclassification: English reported as Scottish

Tags: r

I had tried your the textcat package and function which generally gave satisfactory results, but there are certain anomalies which I hope will be addressed.

For example, the string `“a good thing”`, regardless of the casing arrangement of the letters, will return “Scots” rather than “English”.

The same thing happened if I tried it with the strings or codes:

```
textcat("The human species learned long, long ago that sticking together is a good thing.")
[1] "scots"
textcat("A good thing.")
[1] "scots"
```

I tried other packages as well such as cld2, cld3 and franc, and possibly a few others.

```
detect_language("long ago that sticking together is a good thing")
[1] "en"
```

The package `cld2` provided a correct classification i.e. “en” but I have not tried it more thoroughly with my training and test data sets.

Package `cld3`’s return value is the same as cld2.

```
library("cld3", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")

detect_language("long ago that sticking together is a good thing")
[1] "en"
```

The franc package’s returned “sco” which is consistent with textcat.

```
franc("The human species learned long, long ago that sticking together is a good thing.")
[1] "sco"
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want it to return English more often, maybe run two or three of the packages and if any of them classifies it as English, assume it' s English?

Comment: maybe an accent problem ?

Comment: Here is the string I used to test and detect which  language it will be classified as. "The human species learned long, long ago that sticking together is a good thing." I don't see any accent in play here. I used the textcat package to test if the string would return it as English, as it should since the whole sentence is very obviously, totally in English. No cognates or loanwords that I know of being used here. I tested parts of the string and found out that the string "a good thing" was the culprit.

Comment: The funny thing is, if I tested the string by omitting “a good thing”, it will correctly be reported as English e.g. “. "The human species learned long, long ago that sticking together is”. 

Another funny thing is that, the ones in the string reported as English clearly overwhelms “a good thing” but the whole sentence is still reported as being Scottish.

Thanks a mil.

Comment: I tried cld2 and cld3, though those packages were correct in returning the value "en", they were even less accurate when tested with other strings.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution from the package developer. Dropping Scots is one option. Scots in this matter refers to lowland scots, thus still referring to germanic english. Well, I suspected as much (",)...R> textcat::textcat("The human species learned long, long ago that R> sticking together is a good thing.", textcat::TC_char_profiles[-43]) [1] "english"